# Seeking Android PDF to voice app that can skip citations

Tags: tools

I like to use a PDF to voice app to read papers aloud on walks. I used to use Voice Dream for iOS ($25) but recently switched to Android. Voice Dream is only for iOS.

Voice Dream had a very useful setting that skipped parenthetical citations while reading aloud which was very helpful. Without this feature, the app would not really support my use case because the out-loud citations would be too distracting to listen to.

Can anyone suggest a good Android voice to PDF reader that is good for academic papers? I am fine paying for a good app because I will use it a lot.